# Angular 1.3: Angular Dependencies Not Loaded by Bower

Tags: angularjs, git

I have the following .bowerrc, bower.json and .gitignore files in a project

```
public/.bowerrc
--------------------------
{
  "directory": "/vendor"
}


public/bower.json
--------------------------
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "Me <myemail@gmail.com>"
  ],
  "description": "Loan Operations Application",
  "moduleType": [
    "node"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "http://www.thedomain.com",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.4",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.4",
    "angular-autocomplete": "~1.0.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0",
    "angular-filter": "~0.5.1",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.6.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.4",
    "angular-toastr": "~0.5.2",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.4",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "angular-ui-utils": "~0.1.1",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.*",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.1",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "moment": "~2.8.4",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "ng-grid": "~2.0.14",
    "satellizer": "~0.8.6",
    "angular-permission": "~0.1.4",
    "angular-moment": "~0.8.2",
    "angular-mass-autocomplete": "*"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.4",
    "angular": "~1.3.4",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.4"
  }
}

/.gitignore
------------------------
vendor
public/vendor
public/angular/logs
composer.phar
composer.lock
bootstrap/start.php
bootstrap/compiled.php
.env.*.php
.env.php
public/angular/constants.js
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
.idea
```

I git clone the repo, run composer install in the root (to load Laravel dependencies) and cd into /public and run bower install but the vendor directory is not created and the dependencies are not installed. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: what is the `vendor` directory? `bower install` only create a directory `bower_components`

Comment: that's why I have the .bowerrc file, to tell it to use vendor and not bower_components

Comment: ok it seems the directory is pointing to vender under root? `/vendor`, should be just `vendor` as a relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only think of 2 things.

1. File permissions. reset all folders and files in your project root to 755 and user you logged in. Including project folder itself.
2. Looking at your structure make sure you run `bower install` inside `public` folder not inside your project root where you run `composer`.

Comment: Do you think the .bowerrc file should say 'public/vendor'?

Comment: First of all this file have to be in the same folder where your bower.json file is. If this file is in `public` folder then `.bowerrc` have to be also there and no public in the file. If your `bower.json` is in the root, then yes, it should be `public/vendor`. But since I do not see your structure I can only guess.

Comment: it was the file permissions

Answer (score 0):

```
public/.bowerrc
--------------------------
{
  "directory": "vendor"
}
```